# ijavascript won't integrate in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: javascript, npm, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to install ijavascript for use within Jupyter Notebook, but unfortunately I can't proceed with the ijs command. 
This is my output log:

```
Simons-MacBook-Pro-2:~ simonzimmermann$ npm install ijavascript
npm WARN ijavascript-test@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN ijavascript-test@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ ijavascript@5.0.20
updated 1 package in 3.463s
Simons-MacBook-Pro-2:~ simonzimmermann$ ijs
-bash: ijs: command not found
```

I already tried to reinstall npm and ijavascript but I still can't do ijs, and thus, can't create a javascript in Jupyter notebook.

cheers,
Simon

Comment: You should put the output into your question as text (using code formatting) rather than an image as it's easier to read.

Comment: `ijs` probably isn't in your path. Run `updatedb` then `locate ijs | grep bin`.

Comment: Unfortunately, updatedb results in the following:

     Simons-MacBook-Pro-2:~ simonzimmermann$ updatedb
     -bash: updatedb: command not found

Comment: Try just the locate part

Comment: thanks, just the locate part worked!
sorry for waiting so long with the reply and thanks again!